# Stratified sample when some strata are too small

Tags: r, sampling, random

I need to draw a stratified sample with `n` observation in each stratum, but some strata have fewer observations than `n`. If a stratum has too few observations (say, `k<n` observations), I want to sample all `k` observations from that stratum.

```
require(sampling)

n <- 10
geo_ID <- c(rep(1, times = 20), rep(2, times = 20), rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), times = 5))
    set.seed(42)
V1 <- rnorm(60, 0, 1)
V2 <- rnorm(60, 2, 1)

DF <- data.frame(geo_ID = geo_ID, V1 = V1, V2 = V2)
    #Sort as explained in ?strata help file
DF <- DF[order(DF[, "geo_ID"]), ]

strata(DF, stratanames = "geo_ID", size = c(n, n, n, n), method = "srswor")
```

If I use sampling without replacement as above, I (understandably) get the error:

```
Error in strata(DF, stratanames = "geo_ID", size = c(10, 10, 10, 10),  : 
  not enough obervations in the stratum
```

Sampling with replacement avoids the error, `method = "srswr"`, but that's not ideal since it sometimes draws repeats for strata that are sufficiently large to have only unique sample draws.

NOTE: There's a similar question on SO but it wasn't really answered. Also I think this question is more general. ([Stratified sampling - not enough observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268963/stratified-sampling-not-enough-observations)) The answers to the linked question are not generally useful since they require either (i) sample sizes proportional  to the stratum size (whereas, I need a fixed number) or (ii) manually programming stratum-by-stratum, which isn't feasible as the number of strata increases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question about how to do this with the "sampling" package, but I've written [**a function called `stratified`**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6424112) that will do this for you.

If you have "devtools" installed, you can load it like this:

```
library(devtools)
source_gist(6424112)
```

Otherwise, just copy the code of the function from the Gist into your session and have fun.

---

Usage is simple:

```
set.seed(1) ## So you can reproduce this
stratified(DF, group = "geo_ID", size = 10)
# Some groups
# ---3, 4---
# contain fewer observations than desired number of samples.
# All observations have been returned from those groups.
#    geo_ID          V1        V2
# 7       1  1.51152200 2.3358481
# 9       1  2.01842371 2.9207286
# 14      1 -0.27878877 1.0464766
# 20      1  1.32011335 0.9002191
# 5       1  0.40426832 1.2727079
# :::SNIP:::
# 43      3  0.75816324 0.9967914
# 47      3 -0.81139318 1.5777441
# 55      3  0.08976065 0.3389009
# 51      3  0.32192527 1.9749074
# 48      4  1.44410126 1.8776498
# 44      4 -0.72670483 3.8484819
# 60      4  0.28488295 2.1372562
# 52      4 -0.78383894 2.1080727
# 56      4  0.27655075 1.6176663
```

---

There are some "fun" features, like subsetting your strata in the function itself:

```
## Selects only "geo_ID" values equal to 1 or 4
stratified(DF, group = "geo_ID", size = 10, select = list(geo_ID = c(1, 4)))
```

... taking a proportionate sample:

```
## Just set the size argument to a value less than 1
stratified(DF, group = "geo_ID", size = .1)
```

... and using multiple columns as your groups. The comments at the Gist include some examples to try out.

Comment: Thank you! One question, in my real data I have multiple geographic ID fields, some numeric and some character. The function above works for the numeric one (town IDs), but when I run it on the character field (town names), I get this response:  `Error in if (length(x) == 1L && is.numeric(x) && x >= 1) { :   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Although it might be impossible to know without the data, maybe you have a clue since you wrote the function.

Comment: @DTRM, sorry. I've been away for a few days. I'll try to see if I can recreate your error. Otherwise, if you have some sample data that recreates the error, please update your question and ping me in the comments here.

Comment: @AHandcartAndMohair The Gist link is currently broken: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6424112

Comment: Is [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64329874/mstage-for-multistage-sampling-from-sampling-package-in-r) also related to your sampling method?