# Customize the stratified sample strategy in `boot` package

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to obtain the bootstrapping SEs for regression coefficients. The using data looks like:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(1:30), 
             fac1 = as.factor(sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"),30, replace = T)),
             fac2 = as.factor(sample(c("NY","NC","CA"),30,replace = T)),
             x = rnorm(1:30))
```

I am using `boot` package to perform the bootstrapping:

```
library(boot)
fun <- function(data, index){
    data <- df[index,]
    reg <- lm(y ~ fac1 + fac2 + x, data)
    coef(reg)
}
test.boot <- boot(df, fun, strata = df$fac1, 100)
```

However, R complains：

```
Error in boot(df, fun, strata = df$fac1, 100) : 
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

My situation is exactly the same as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270152/stratified-sample-when-some-strata-are-too-small). I understand the problem here is the insufficient observations in each groups. The `strata` option in `boot` package seems can only work for one factor variable. In my case, I should stratify the samples based on two factors: `fac1` and `fac2` (please let me know if my understanding is not correct here).

I find out that function `stratified` posted [here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6424112) can produce exact stratified samples as I need. The problem here is how can I implement the `stratified` function to the `boot` function and let the `boot` function works on the correct samples?

Currently, I am writing a `for-loop` myself to run the bootstrapping using correct stratified samples. But I still want to know whether I can incorporate the `stratified` function into `boot`? Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: See `help("interaction")` for building a single factor from 2 factors.

Comment: Thanks @lmao. I think using "interaction" is definitely a good way to solve the above question. I am still curious about if I can incorporate other customized function, like `stratified` mentioned here, into `boot` since I may need extra features provided by `stratified` for more complex situations. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After analyzing the `boot` package carefully, I think I find a solution to my question without modifying the original code of `boot`. Actually, `boot` provides a way to let user customize his sampling strategy. Check the `sim = "parametric"` and `ran.gen` options in `help(boot)`.

So, as to my case, I can simply specify the `ran.gen` function to nest the `stratified` function and use it to regenerate samples for bootstrapping.

```
fun <- function(data){
            reg <- lm(y ~ fac1 + fac2 + x, data)
            coef(reg)}

rgen <- function(df,stratified){
        #code of stratified goes here and other specifications ... }

test.boot <- boot(df, fun, 1000, sim = "parametric", ran.gen = rgen)
```

Done!